# .gradle\caches\6.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradle-cache

I've tried to delete .gradle folder or delete last-build.bin file, but it isn't work. Could everyone have the solution to this problem ? thank you...

Answer (score 3):

**One simple solution is**

I believe that another solution for that could as much be related to hidden folders. If that is the problem:

1. Check if your *User* folder is not hidden *C:/User..*
2. On the tab menu, select *View*.
3. On your far right there will be *Options*, select.
4. It will display *Folder Options* with the following tabs: General, View and Search. Here again, be sure to select *View*.
5. Navigate to *Hidden files and folders*.
6. And under that folder, just select Show hidden files and folders radio button.

Should that not do the trick, then move on to check if ALL the folders related to that path all the way to *Caches* are not hidden. The culprit here, should be that the: *.gradle\caches* is hidden.

Therefore, tap on the folder and unhide it activating the Caches folder(don't open it - just select it) and clicking *View* once again. Just next to *Options* on your far right, there should be *Unhide selected items* on the left. Of course, Unhide them and wait until the attributes are well applied. Now you are good to go, you should not experience that problem any longer.

*I think that should do the trick if by any means your folder got hidden. Be sure to do that first, before following any of those technical steps. If your folders are hidden, Android Studio or Intelli j for that matters, cannot access the path in question.*

Answer (score 0):

Please check C:\Users\yourname folder
is this folder hidden?
try this :

1. rightclick folder-> attr
2. uncheck hidden

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not aware of the cause of the problem, I resolved this issue by

1. Deleting the last-build.bin file
2. Re-enabling full file access to Android Studio.

[image]